# Find a string and delete row in table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, find

I am trying to excecute a VBA macro from excel to remove a row in a word document if a string is present.

```
For i = startItem To endItem
Dim msWord      As Object
Set msWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

With msWord
    .Visible = TRUE
    .Documents.Open getSetting("PTC TEMPLATE")        'path of the template in msword format
    .Activate
    'Remove TEST ROW
    'LOOP TEST TO REMOVE
    Dim DirArray        As Variant
    DirArray = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("valveList").ListObjects("valveList").HeaderRowRange.value
    
    For Each element In DirArray
        If element Like "*TEST*" Then
            Debug.Print element & "--> " & Range("valveList[" & element & "]")(i).value
            If Range("valveList[" & element & "]")(i).value = "NO" Then
                .ActiveDocument.Select
                With .Selection.Range.Find
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                    .Text = Range("valveList[" & element & "]")(i).value        'Find all strings in col A
                    .Forward = TRUE
                    .Wrap = wdFindStop
                    .MatchCase = FALSE
                    .MatchWholeWord = FALSE
                    .Execute
                    If .Found = TRUE Then
                        
                        .Selection.Rows.Delete
                    End If
                    
                End With
                
            End If
            
        End If
    Next element
    'End REMOVE TEST ROW
```

Here I have the problem that I dont know how to refer to the found string and delete the row of the table the string belongs to.

I'm not very familiar with VBA, if someone can revise my code and explain how to solve this problem I'll be thankful

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous problems with your code, including repeatedly starting Word and opening a new copy of the document you're modifying, employing Word constants with late binding, and the use of unqualified Range references. Try something along the lines of:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim msWord  As Object, wdDoc As Object, xlSht As Worksheet, DirArray As Variant
Set xlSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("valveList")
DirArray = xlSht.ListObjects("valveList").HeaderRowRange.Value
Set msWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
With msWord
  .Visible = True
  .ScreenUpdating = False
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(GetSetting("PTC TEMPLATE"))        'path of the template in msword format
  For i = startItem To endItem
    For Each element In DirArray
      If element Like "*TEST*" Then
        If xlSht.Range("valveList[" & element & "]")(i).Value = "NO" Then
          With wdDoc.Range
            With .Find
              .ClearFormatting
              .Replacement.ClearFormatting
              .Text = xlSht.Range("valveList[" & element & "]")(i).Text        'Find all strings in col A
              .Forward = True
              .Wrap = 0 'wdFindStop
              .MatchCase = False
              .MatchWholeWord = False
            End With
            Do While .Find.Execute
              If .Information(12) = True Then 'wdWithInTable
                .Rows(1).Delete
              End If
              .Collapse 0 'wdCollapseEnd
            Loop
          End With
        End If
      End If
    Next element
  Next i
  .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```